# WFS polygon query of line string

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I want to query the polygon geometry and get features which are intersecting borders and within the polygon , but i am getting the features within BBOX of polygon .

my query is like this.

service:WFS,

request:GetFeature,

version:1.1.0,

typename:mystore:flightRout,

outputFormat:json,

srsname:EPSG:3857,

cql_filter:INTERSECTS(geometry,POLYGON((12.95269334858834 75.65514701171875
,12.95269334858834 76.11107962890625
,13.455397924014989 76.11107962890625
,13.455397924014989 75.65514701171875
,12.95269334858834 75.65514701171875))
)

Comment: Your code seems to indicate that the coordinates are in 3857, but your polygon is in 4326. Also, I think you have the coordinates reversed - if you look at it in a viewer, you get a box off the coast of Greenland.

Comment: But after the versions they are taking coordinates in reverse only. I will try with the projection changed to 4326

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce with the OpenGEO (Boundless) demo server http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs.

This image shows data from feature type "ne_110m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land" and a polygon to be inserted into CQL_FILTER

[image]

The WFS GetFeature request made according to your request is then

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=getfeature&typename=osm:ne_110m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land&cql_filter=INTERSECTS%28the_geom,POLYGON%28%289.0127%20%20-4.9233%20,24.9746%20-4.9233%20,24.9746%2020.0597%20,9.0127%2020.0597%20,9.0127%20%20-4.9233%20%29%29%29

And the result on a map is correct with all the linestrings inside the box and also all linestrings which are only partly inside the box.

[image]

Now the question is what is different in your system or data. You should prepare a complete and tested way for reproducing your issue: Which GeoServer version, which data, how to make a store and a layer from the data.

BTW. the only official output format for WFS is GML and therefore you should use that for debugging even if you finally need GeoJSON.